# setting Ubuntu resolution to outside default

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a Dell UltraSharp 40 Curved WUHD Monitor - U4021QW that can handle resolutions up to 5120 x 2160 (DisplayPort: 60 Hz, HDMI: 30 Hz). I'm using a high end HDMI cable, so I'm expecting 5120 x 2160 @30Hz. I have have run though https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/ multiple times.

I have set up the file `/etc/profile.d/external_monitor_resol.sh`:

```
xrandr --newmode "5120x2160_30.00"  949.00  5120 5536 6096 7072  2160 2163 2173 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "5120x2160_30.00"
```

I have reset the machine and checked the resolution in the GUI and the new profile is there, however, when I select it, it just reverts back to 2560 x 1080.

Does anyone know why is that and what I'm doing wrong?